# QMake pointing to wrong directory

Tags: 20.04, qt

I am trying to build cpp project that has is dependent from Qt. I have installed the Qt in the folder opt.

The Qt home directory is: `/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64`
The qmake executable is located in the directory: `/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/bin`

When I run the command  `make clean` or `make install` it fails with the error below:

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile cloudscrape.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui core-private gui-private platformcompositor_support-private fontdatabase_support-private eventdispatcher_support-private theme_support-private
make: *** [Makefile:245: Makefile] Error 3
```

When I run the command `qmake -v`, it shows the following result:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

It is very strange that the path of qmake in error is `/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake`. I have tried to change the `qmake` directory path implementing the following actions:

- I have check `PATH` varible and it points to the correct QT. Below is the value of the `PATH`:

```
PATH=/home/rando/.pyenv/shims:/home/rando/.pyenv/bin:/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin:/home/rando/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:/home/rando/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/bin
```

- Modified the qtchooser configuration file, after this qmake points to right directory , I confirmed by running the command below:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.9 in /opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/lib
```

But still the problem persists, because when I run `make clean` or `make install` the it is using the wrong directory:

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile cloudscrape.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui core-private gui-private platformcompositor_support-private fontdatabase_support-private eventdispatcher_support-private theme_support-private
make: *** [Makefile:245: Makefile] Error 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issues by restarting the machine.
I think the problem was with cached configuration and starting a new session helped clear.

- Modify the qtchooser configuration file

  - find the configuration file with command : `locate qtchooser | grep conf`
  - modify with your favorite editor: `sudo gedit ${path}/qtchooser/qt5.conf` like below:

```
/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/lib
/opt/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64
```

- Start a new session